# For-each loop XML components that stored in variable in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

So I'd give a little background about my question. We have a trading software and it generates data in XML format first and then we develop XSLT to convert XML data into CSV output. Also we have a developed function which allows us to retrieve data from Oracle DB so if in some case the information is not available in XML file we can get from DB instead.

Now, within XSLT I declare one variable, this variable get data from DB and returns data in XML format, like below:

```
<basket>
  <component>123</component>
  <component>134</component>
  <component>145</component>
  ....
</basket>
```

Then I need to loop through each of these components and for each component I need to add other information accordingly. You can imagine component as trade-id, what I want to do is based on the trade-id I'll populate other columns like trade-date, counterparty, instrument name, etc.

**My desired output is:**

trade-id, trade-date, counterparty, trader

123, 15-JAN-17, BOA,123
134, 03-OCT-17, SG, 209
135, 22-SEP-16, BOA, 323
.......

Our original XML looks like below:

```
<ns0:BasicTransaction>
        <ns0:BusinessEvent>Purchase/Sale</ns0:BusinessEvent>
        <ns0:TransactionInternalCode>228480020</ns0:TransactionInternalCode>
        <ns0:InstrumentInternalCode>70299110</ns0:InstrumentInternalCode>
        <ns0:Quantity>0.890000000000</ns0:Quantity>
        <ns0:Notional>8900000.000000000000</ns0:Notional>
</ns0:BasicTransaction>
```

First time post here, please help or advise if you have any ideas. Also please comment below if you're not quite sure on my question or need more information.

Really appreciate in advance!

Comment: Can you post more of your XML please? In particular, where is the other information held. In anycase, it sounds like you may need to make use of an `xsl:key`. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC Thanks for your reply first! For some columns if I can get directly from XML file I'll retrieve from there; and some are NOT available in our original XML file, so I probably have to query DB again based on the each trade-id. (I also add more about how my original XML file looks like)